# Entitybrower access denied for non-admin user

Tags: 8, entities

I have created an entity browser for taxonomy terms that is used as an entity reference select form element on a node. This allows users to browse terms grouped by vocabulary, see synonyms etc. The view that it is using has the permission "View published content" and all users including anonymous have this permission. I do not see any permission settings in the entity browser setup itself or in the general permissions for the entity browser module.

The browser works well for the admin user but gives an access denied to editor users.
What can I check to investigate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a separate permission for entity browsers - on the permissions page (*/admin/people/permissions*), they're grouped under *Entity Browser*. You'll need to give any roles that will use the browser the **Access [My Browser] pages** permission.